# Count related to date items in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that shows how many are still completing a task at two and 8 weeks.

- Col A Name
- Col B has Start a date
- Col C is the WeekNumber of the date from col A (Using WeekNumber Script)
- Col D has Yes if the task has not been completed in two weeks
- Col E has Yes if the task has not been completed in 8 weeks
- Col F Is a list of week numbers
- Col G Gives me a count of how many start the task in a particular week taken from the week number.
- Col H I need this to be the count of people still completing the task in 2 weeks
- Col I I need this to be the count of people still completing the task in 8 weeks

I am stumped on how to get the count for col I and H.

Answer (score 1):

In the example sheet, RESULT, I added the following formula to cell `G3`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(C3:C;FILTER(F3:F;F3:F<>"")))
```

In the next two columns I added these formulas:

*Column H*

```
=IF(COUNT(FILTER($C$3:C;$C$3:C=F3;$D$3:D="Yes"))=0;"";
    COUNT(FILTER($C$3:C;$C$3:C=F3;$D$3:D="Yes")))
```

*Column I*

```
=IF(COUNT(FILTER($C$3:C;$C$3:C=F3;$E$3:E="Yes"))=0;"";
    COUNT(FILTER($C$3:C;$C$3:C=F3;$E$3:E="Yes")))
```

Copy down the formulas, to cover the whole year.
See example file I've prepared: [EXPECTED vs. RESULT](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFB1OVdxaUp3dk9iU05TakFUZ1FWdGc&usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I probably did not explain my problem very well. What I am looking for is away of counting those who started in a particular week still not completed at 2 weeks. For instance if 7 people started in week 5 and only one has completed then I would expect answer to be 6 for that week No. Not a general count but one specific to each start week.

Comment: @user33789 See my example again. I've used the `FREQUENCY` formula, amongst other formulas. If you like it, I will re-change my answer.

Comment: I have added another sheet to your example to show my problem better. It is the final 2 columns that are causing me the problem. I have put in the figures I would expect in those 2 columns. Which are the number of yeses for a particular week not just the overall number of yeses. I hope that is clear - Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user33789 Take a look at what I have accomplished. Column H has an `ARRAYFORMULA` and I and J have a `FILTER` and `COUNT`. I wanted to have an `ARRAYFORMULA` for the other columns as well, but this solution works !!

Comment: Thank You that works a treat and is just what I was looking for .

Comment: @user33789 Perhaps you can mark my answer as best (and only one...), see [faq#howtoask]. Thanks, JJ